# I am trying to use link component of next js but it is giving me 404 error

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404

I made a navbar of my application.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full  bg-blue-950 px-2.5 py-5 items-center justify-between h-24 ">
      <div className="flex-row">
        <a href="/">
          <Image
            alt="company logo"
            src="/cover.png"
            height={200}
            width={200}
            className="rounded-lg h-16"
          />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className="flex w-1/4 flex-row  not-italic font-bold text-sky-300 text-base justify-evenly">
        <div className="flex flex-row  items-center">
          <a href="/">
            <Image
              src=""
              alt="profil logo"
              className="h-10 rounded-full"
              height={25}
              width={40}
              
            />
          </a>
          <span className="ml-2.5">Amrit</span>
        </div>

        <div className="flex not-italic font-bold text-base text-sky-300 ">
          <ul className="flex flex-row list-none">
            <li className="px-2 py-2 hover:cursor-pointer">
              <Link href="/login" className="no-underline text-white hover:underline">Log in</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="px-2 py-2 hover:cursor-pointer">
              <a href="/" className="no-underline text-white hover:underline">Log out</a>
            </li>
            <li className="px-2 py-2 hover:cursor-pointer">
              <a href="/" className="no-underline text-white hover:underline">Register</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

[this is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZvAm.png)

The problem i am facing is that when i am clicking on the link Log in, it is giving me 404
This page could not be found. I tried a lot but could found any solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to how you are using the Link component from Next.js. The link component should wrap around the element that triggers the navigation.

Make sure you're also defining the "/login" route in your Next.js pages directory. If the issue persists, you might want to check if there are any typos or issues with your project's file structure.

```
<li className="px-2 py-2 hover:cursor-pointer">
  <Link href="/login">
    <a className="no-underline text-white hover:underline">
      Log in
    </a>
  </Link>
</li>
```